# Separate pages for blog posts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on my private CMS, mostly just to learn PHP. For now I have very simple way to show post, using GET with ID, for example www.mypage.com/post.php?id=1 and then loading results from DB. But I see that almost all blogs are using other way, which looks like this www.mypage.com/post/lorem-ipsum. I know about removing file extensions but the rest is mystery. Does wordpress and other blog CMS are somehow creating separate files? PHP is huge, and it's hard to find an answer if you don't know it well, so If someone can point me in the right direction, I'll be obliged.

Comment: https://packagist.org/search/?q=router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to *rewrite* the URL using an `.htaccess` file: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Yes, it looks like exactly something I was looking for. Thanks for really quick answer.